# Drag formulas but 5 by 5

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a way to drag the formula in F16 to all the cells on the right, but if you do this normally, I have the red formulas, but I need the green ones, like, skip 5 cells.

I need a formula that works for all weeks and adds the values.

[image: Excel]

Is possible only with excel formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(13:13,match(F$15,11:11,0)):INDEX(13:13,match(F$15,11:11,0)+4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if available:

```
=TOROW(BYROW(WRAPROWS(F13:T13,5),SUM))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the calendar week per date:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($F$3:$P$3) * (ISOWEEKNUM($F$2:$P$2)=F6))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without referencing the weeknumbers this could be another alternative in cell F16 and filled to the right.

```
=SUM(INDEX(13:13,,6+5*(COLUMN(A1)-COLUMN($A$1))):INDEX(13:13,,10+5*(COLUMN(A1)-COLUMN($A$1))))
```